# Code to change all odd numbered words to even numbered words and vice-versa

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, loops

Full question: Create a method called ChangeWords() that converts all ODD Numbered words in the string to Even Numbered words and vice versa, then prints the results. The string to be changed should be passed to the method as a parameter. For example, the phrase "Now is the time to act!" can be changed to "is Now time to act!" Write the python code and subsequent pseudocode for the same, where the string is given by the user via the keyboard.
Input: Read a string
Ouput: Changecase string(all ODD Numbered words in the string to Even Numbered words and vice versa)
Boundary : If the string is "None" or "NONE", the print "NONE String"

```
def ChangeWords(wr):
    res=[]
    w1=wr.split()
    for index in range(len(w1)):
        for j in w1:
            if index%2==0:
                res.append(j[index-1])
            else:
                res.append(j[index+1])
    return ''.join(res)
str1=input()
if str1=="NONE"or str1=="none":
    print("NONE String")
else:
    print(ChangeWords(str1))
```

why won't this work? I can't understand why it's showing index out of range. Can someone please explain.

```
s1=input()
l1=s1.split()
nl=[]
i=1
for item in l1:
    if i%2==0:
        nl.insert(i-1,l1[i])
    else:
        nl.insert(i+1,l1[i])
    i+=1
print(nl)
```

I tried the same program without using functions but I guess the logic is the same because I'm getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are looping on the number of words given in your string not the number of character in each sub string. Let's say you give a string "a b c d" to your function ChangeWrods. Your index would be a 0, 1, 2 or 3 but the words are only 1 character long and so accessible only by index 0.
So you need to change the logic of your function to loop through a range of 0 to len(parsed_word)
Hope that helped

Comment: even in the code of the bottom one?